# Как происходит вызов функций в React/Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

[Есть пример из документации на git](https://github.com/triodjangopiter/redux/blob/master/examples/counter/src/components/Counter.js)

И в методе `render` есть `<button onClick={onIncrement}>`. Помогите понять как это работает. `onIncrement` это вроде просто переменная, да еще и константа, почему она висит на `onClick`? Разве там не должен быть вызов функции? Объясните пожалуйста в чем тут логика? Спасибо.

```
  render() {
    const { value, onIncrement, onDecrement } = this.props
    return (
      <p>
        Clicked: {value} times
        {' '}
        <button onClick={onIncrement}>
          +
        </button>
        {' '}
        <button onClick={onDecrement}>
          -
        </button>
        {' '}
        <button onClick={this.incrementIfOdd}>
          Increment if odd
        </button>
        {' '}
        <button onClick={this.incrementAsync}>
          Increment async
        </button>
      </p>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы посмотрите код вашего примера, то увидите такую конструкцию:

```
Counter.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  onIncrement: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onDecrement: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

она означает, что компонент ожидает получить функции в пропсы `onIncrement` и `onDecrement`. Соответственно, onIncrement и onDecrement - функции. Чтобы узнать, какие это функции, надо найти контейнер, в котором этот компонент подключается. Там вы увидите, что передается в эти пропсы.

Answer (score 1):

Из этого куска кода неясно, является ли это просто переменной либо чем-то еще. Но что-то подсказывает, что это переменная, которая ссылается на функцию, и переданная через props.
Для того чтобы понять как это работает, смотрите на функцию/класс, которая передает этот параметр. Для объяснения, было бы неплохо показать/ссылку полный код.

Comment: Ссылка есть в первой строке, но я Вас понял. Спасибо.